# JavaScript Flip Counter

Tags: javascript, animation, counter, flip

I would like to include a flip counter on my site, similar to what Apple was using for their [1 billion app countdown](http://www.macrumors.com/2009/04/10/apple-launches-1-billion-app-countdown-promotion/).

[image]

Can anyone get their JavaScript to work standalone?

***If anyone can provide working code, that would be great.***

Comment: Forget JS - you gonna steal their slick "flippy" background image, or draw your own...?

Comment: I don't know JS well enough to write my own, hence the reason for asking the question

Comment: Are you going to use it to show how many visitors your page has had? :p

Comment: @Steve, too bad I didn't read your comment earlier. The linked old 1 billion apps countdown was just a static page when I enhanced the question, while the more recent 10 billion songs countdown was still actually counting. Even today, the 10 billion song countdown is still dynamic, though the countdown has finished and the countdown script only shows you some result page with an image. So even today I think http://www.apple.com/itunes/10-billion-song-countdown/ is a much better example (and was more likely to be searched for during the last weeks) than the static old link.

Comment: See also http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter/ (to which I'm in no way related).

Answer (score 25):

They're using a combination of CSS and JavaScript. The flip animation is powered by a [CSS Sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)-like technique.

First of all, they have a very tall image called `filmstrip.png` that contains every flip "state" for each number (0 to 9; have a look at [a scaled-down detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwaVW.png) and you'll see what I mean).

Then, in the HTML, each digit is made up of three nested elements:

- The first is a container element, which has its `width` and `height` set to the dimensions of a single flip "state", and its `overflow` set to `hidden`. This element is positioned relatively.
- The second element is positioned absolutely (and because the first element is positioned relatively, this second element is positioned absolutely *relative* to the first element).
- The third element has its `background-image` set to `filmstrip.png`, and its `width` and `height` set to the dimensions of this image.

The JavaScript then seems to rapidly change the `top` property of the second element, causing different parts of `filmstrip.png` to be exposed one after another, thus resulting in a flip animation.

Steve

Comment: No, but I do have Safari 4's Web Inspector (http://www.apple.com/safari/features.html#developer)...

Answer (score 24):

Here it is, ready to be implemented in your own webpage
http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/

Comment: Hey do you have a method for creating the bg images similar to that? I can find tons of freebies with a similar design but it's difficult to create the "flipping" effect.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a counter that works great with very minimal javascript to give it a little "brain":

[image]

```js
function Counter(selector, settings){
  this.settings = Object.assign({
    digits: 5,
    delay: 250, // ms
    direction: ''  // ltr is default
  }, settings||{})
  
  var scopeElm = document.querySelector(selector)
  
  // generate digits markup
  var digitsHTML = Array(this.settings.digits + 1).join('<div><b data-value="0"></b></div>')
  scopeElm.innerHTML = digitsHTML;

  this.DOM = {
    scope : scopeElm,
    digits : scopeElm.querySelectorAll('b')
  }
  
  this.DOM.scope.addEventListener('transitionend', e => {
    if (e.pseudoElement === "::before" && e.propertyName == 'margin-top'){
      e.target.classList.remove('blur')
    }
  })
  
  this.count()
}

Counter.prototype.count = function(newVal){
  var countTo, className, 
      settings = this.settings,
      digitsElms = this.DOM.digits;
  
  // update instance's value
  this.value = newVal || this.DOM.scope.dataset.value|0

  if( !this.value ) return;
  
  // convert value into an array of numbers
  countTo = (this.value+'').split('')
  
  if(settings.direction == 'rtl'){
    countTo = countTo.reverse()
    digitsElms = [].slice.call(digitsElms).reverse()
  }
  
  // loop on each number element and change it
  digitsElms.forEach(function(item, i){ 
      if( +item.dataset.value != countTo[i]  &&  countTo[i] >= 0 )
        setTimeout(function(j){
            var diff = Math.abs(countTo[j] - +item.dataset.value);
            item.dataset.value = countTo[j]
            if( diff > 3 )
              item.className = 'blur';
        }, i * settings.delay, i)
  })
}



/////////////// create new counter for this demo ///////////////////////

var counter = new Counter('.numCounter', {direction:'rtl', delay:200, digits:7})
setInterval(randomCount, 3000)

function randomCount(){
  counter.count( getRandomNum(0, 9999999))
}

function getRandomNum(min,max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1) + min)
}
```

```css
.numCounter {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: normal;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.numCounter > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
}

.numCounter > div > b {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0.1em;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.numCounter > div > b::before {
  content: ' 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ';
  display: block;
  word-break: break-all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0.15, 0.6, 1.15), text-shadow 150ms;
  transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.75, 0.15, 0.6, 1.15), text-shadow 150ms;
}

.numCounter > div > b.blur {
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 
               0 0.1em 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 
               0 0.3em 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 
               0 -0.1em 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6), 
               0 -0.3em 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.numCounter > div > b[data-value="1"]::before { margin-top: -90px; }
.numCounter > div > b[data-value="2"]::before { margin-top: -180px;}
.numCounter > div > b[data-value="3"]::before { margin-top: -270px;}
.numCounter > div > b[data-value="4"]::before { margin-top: -360px;}
.numCounter > div > b[data-value="5"]::before { margin-top: -450px;}
.numCounter > div > b[data-value="6"]::before { margin-top: -540px;}
.numCounter > div > b[data-value="7"]::before { margin-top: -630px;}
.numCounter > div > b[data-value="8"]::before { margin-top: -720px;}
.numCounter > div > b[data-value="9"]::before { margin-top: -810px;}

.numCounter > div:nth-last-child(3n)::before {
  content: ",";
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  opacity: .6;
  color: white;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.numCounter {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: .4em;
  text-align: center;
 
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: black;
}
.numCounter b {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class='numCounter' data-value='1839471'></div>
```

It looks great and performs live very well, and it it count from any number to any number.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for the same thing I found a commercial product offering this functionality: [Sprite Countdown Flip](http://codecanyon.net/item/gaur-countdown-with-animation/2665769?ref=oberto).

Note: I'm not affiliated with this product; but it's well done and might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the open source variant: [FlipclockJS](http://flipclockjs.com/), which probably was created right after this event :)

Github: [objectivehtml/FlipClock](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock), available via NPM and Bower (not maintained)