# Is there a flash or javascript Solari Board available for use on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, user-interface

I'm working on a web page which will display information updated periodically via javascript. I want to have it displayed in a [Solari Board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solari_departure_board), complete with the flipping tiles animation. Is there an existing Flash or Javascript implementation I can use?

[the real thing http://grab.by/42yp](http://grab.by/42yp)

Here's my super-lousy javascript test for one letter. The solution should take a string and figure out how to flip the existing letters to update it. On a real board they all start at once and each stop after the number of flips needed.

[My demo](http://www.adambox.org/solari.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume from the picture you used that you've seen this?

http://blog.elctech.com/2009/01/22/actionscript-solari-departure-board/

Maybe good for anyone else who is looking though.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/746353/416630) here on Stack Overflow.

That led me to [this example](http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter/).

I think that person has worked out all the "nitty gritty" of doing the flip animation.  That should be all you need to put together a working Solari board.

good luck.