# Looking for an effect but don't know the name of it so I can't really search for it

Tags: jquery, effects, counter

I'm attempting to make an effect for a counter on a website, similar to the one that you could see on [old tran stations timetables](http://www.hanselchalets.com/images/station01.jpg) (how the numbers on the right side of the picture changed) either that or the effect where a number goes up as the new number comes from underneath much like how cars change the number that displays the amount of kilometers traveled.

I need some examples to get started but can't think on the name of it. Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://keith-wood.name/flightBoard.html

(the site seems quite slow or heavy, didn't look into that, but the effect seems to be what you're looking for)

Answer (score 1):

I would call that a flip counter. Have a look at this [JavaScript Flip Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746353/javascript-flip-counter)

The famous example is the [apple 1 billion app counter](http://www.macrumors.com/2009/04/10/apple-launches-1-billion-app-countdown-promotion/)