# JS, jQuery loose-leaf calendar effect plugin

Tags: javascript, calendar, effect, folding

Is there `JS` plugin,e.g. `jQuery` or any other,that imitates effect of loose-leaf calendar?

Here is image of calendar.

It's needed, that top half falls into bottom when changing date in calendar.

[image]

Perhaps, [jQuery Accordion](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion)  is closest,but it imitates a little bit other effect.

Comment: I don't know such a plugin yet. But I could work on it. Anyway there are several ways to solve this: CSS3 Animations, Canvas, and single frames of the wanted animation saved in a sprite. I would recommend the CSS3 way. It doesn't require much ressource and falls back on a simple, abrupt change.

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746353/javascript-flip-counter, demo from one of the links: http://cnanney.com/journal/demo/apple-counter-revisited/

Comment: @welldan97, thank you for helpful links,i'll give you feedback as soon try them.Actually,you can post them as answer also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this question: [JavaScript Flip Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746353/javascript-flip-counter)

And this is a demo from one of the links: http://cnanney.com/journal/demo/apple-counter-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this article in the past, though not implemented it.

http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter/

---

Edit: I have just seen [welldan97](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319918/welldan97)'s comment, he should post an answer and get some credit for being before me.