# Animating a Rolodex Flip-Down Effect with jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, setinterval, css-transitions

So I've built a very small demo of an old fashioned rolodex-style clock. The graphics are from a freebie PSD and I've built the clock functionality using setInterval(). You can check out [the live demo here](http://byjakewithlove.com/code/rolodex/).

What I'm trying to do is animate the change in numbers so that the top part "flips" down to display the new number. I'm definitely lost as to how I should go about this - I could use bg images but I feel that numbers in straight HTML are more user-friendly. Can anybody point me in the right direction for this? I would love any help I can get... I also included a preview image below so you can get an idea of what I'm building.

Also I'm open to trying a CSS3 solution, but I haven't found one which works better than jQuery thus far.

[image: jquery clock preview]

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Flip Counter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746353/javascript-flip-counter)

Comment: Try this plugin: http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/example/

Comment: @Widor yes I did find that and also a great example [here](http://cnanney.com/journal/demo/apple-counter-revisited/). however they are using a whole slew of BG images, I'd like to manipulate the HTML elements directly and twist/contort them using jQuery. I could use BG images I suppose - but I'm not great at photoshop so I am wary to use that method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Also the demo doesn't appear to be working since the timer is stuck to 0:0:0. I will keep looking, though, and worst-case scenario I can fall back to a background sprite image similar to Apple.

Comment: You're right - the timer on the demo has now passed, but download it and try it, as it fits your criteria of not using images.

Comment: @Widor Also I'm not looking to build a countdown, but a clock which has a similar animation. I couldn't use that script because I'm not counting downloads but counting seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit this is only half an answer; it shows how to use CSS/JQuery to animate the rolling effect.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="transformjs.1.0.beta.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {font-size:128px;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){  //OnInit

$('.anim').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({    rotateX: '-='+(Math.PI/2),  },500,"",
    function(){ //OnComplete
    var n=(parseInt($(this).html())+1)%10;  //Turn 7 into 8, etc.
    $(this).html(n.toString());    //Update number while it is hidden
    $(this).animate({    rotateX: '+='+(Math.PI/2)  },500); //Rotate it back
    }
  );    
});  


});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="anim" style="float:left">1</div><div class="anim" style="float:left">2</div><div class="anim" style="float:left">3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It needs JQuery 1.5.1+, and the [transformjs library](http://transformjs.strobeapp.com/), which can be [downloaded here](http://www.github.com/sproutcore/transformjs/downloads).
Click on each number to spin it. Tested in Firefox 11 and Chromium 17; transform.js should do something that will work in older browsers and IE.

BTW, speaking of cross-browser challenges, I originally had the three numbers on `<span>`s. This works in Firefox, but Chrome won't animate them! Hence the change to the `<div>`s with `float:left`.

Like I said, it is only half a solution, as it does not quite look like a flip card yet. I think this can be done with a bit of masking, and creating a temporary div on top of the number (the real div will have the next number; the previous number will be in that temporary div, on top). But I couldn't get that working before I ran out of time.

I still thought it was worth posting though; try adding a rotateY and rotateZ, alongside the rotateX in the animation, for some really kewl effects.